# Can I programmatically determine what fonts I can use with GD?

Tags: php, gd

I want to put text over an image using GD.

When I use

```
ImageTTFText($image, $fontSize, $fontRotation, 7, 22, $colorShadow, 'arial.ttf', $str);
```

I get

> Warning: imagettftext()
>   [function.imagettftext]: Could not
>   find/open font in
>   /home/index.php
>   on line 17

Can I get PHP or GD to return a list of all available fonts per my system?

Thanks

### Update

... or do I need to upload myself all the fonts myself that I wish GD to have access to?

Answer (score 1):

Replace `"arial.ttf"` with `"./arial.ttf"`, because `"arial.ttf"` is an absolute path and you need a relative path. Read more on imagettftext [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php).

To answer your update, yes, you do need the font files in that directory. Here is a really cool site for finding fonts (like arial.ttf): http://www.1001freefonts.com/

Download a font file from there, put it in the folder of your script, and then replace "arial.ttf" with "./filename.ttf".

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Imagemagick there is always [that](http://www.rubblewebs.co.uk/imagemagick/server/fonts.php)

Answer (score 0):

The fonts can be anywhere,but you must specify the full path to arial.ttf.